# Own user account is not listed with `net user`

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts

Using Windows 10, version 1809. Say my user account is `Fred`.

From the command prompt, `cd %HOMEPATH%`, takes me to `C:\Users\Fred`. In `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\User Accounts\Manage Accounts`, my account is listed (along with two others, one an administrator account and the other `ASP.NET`).

But from the command prompt `net user` lists a number of accounts, but no `Fred`. When I run `control userpasswords2`, my own `Fred` acount is not displayed, though a total of four are listed.

From Windows Powershell, I ran the following command:

```
get-wmiobject -class "win32_account" -namespace "root\cimv2" | sort caption | format-table caption, __CLASS, FullName
```

which listed a surprisingly large number of accounts...though not `Fred`!

Another problem, which seems related. When I attempt to take control of a file in %windir%\system32 as follows:

- Right-click file and select `Properties`
- `Security` tab, click `Advanced`
- Next to the `TrustedInstaller` account, click `Change`
- In `Enter the object name to select`, type `Fred`
- When I click `Check Names`, an error appears that `An object (User, Group or Built-in security principle) with the following name cannot be found (etc)`

In `Task Manager`, on the `Users` tab, my account is listed as `User` (not `Fred`) and I *am* able to take control of files with the `User` account. But the weird thing is that when `Check names` is clicked, `User` immediately changes to `Fred`!

Why is the current logged-in user listed inconsistently and be unable to take control of the ownership of a file?

Comment: First one: Net User does not show me either. I am logged in.   Second one:  Control Userpasswords2 brings up a dialogue window. Do you get this?  I show up there the same as going to Users and Groups.  Right Click on Computer (that icon) and select Manage, Users and Groups. What does this give you?

Comment: @John: `control userpasswords2` lists four accounts on the `Users` tab (though not my account). On the `Advanced` tab, `Advanced user management > Advanced > Users`, eight accounts are listed. Now this is interesting...the `Name` column lists an account called `User`with a `Full Name` of `FRED`! When did my user account change from `FRED` to `User\FRED`?

Comment: User\Fred is not a name. Just Fred is a name. I get more accounts as well in Users and Groups - System Accounts. So that is normal as well. Did you happen to try to change the name of your Profile in Windows Explorer?

Comment: Your Username is `user`. Your FullName is `Fred`. Just two different properties for the same account. Although it sounds like your username was `Fred` at some point and it was changed to `user` because your C:\Users folder reflects usernames, not fullnames but does not change if you change your username.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds like the answer. At some point the username changed from `Fred` to `User`, though this raises the question of when and why. I certainly knowingly took no action to change my username. Could a Windows update have done this? About two weeks ago, an update on Shutdown was interrupted by a power cut. These anomalies (eg. of being unable to take control of files using `Fred`) were only noticed recently, in the last week or so.

Comment: Windows updates will not change the Profile name. So something is wrong with the OS, or else something tried to change it. A Windows 10 Repair Install will not fix this so far as I know, so for a proper fix, you need to back up data (documents) and reinstall Windows.